# How to play system sounds on internal speakers and music on external?

Tags: windows-8, audio, bluetooth

How do I play system sounds (Windows 8) on internal speakers (built-in audio device) and music on my external bluetooth speakers?

I have managed to get "communication" audio on the internal speakers while playing music on the external speakers. But I still get "boing" and "ding-dong" system sounds on the external speakers which is very annoying.

Machine: Acer Aspire 7600U

External speakers: JBL SB200

[image: Devices]

[image]

Comment: I like all sound but the system and communication sounds to be played on the external speakers. And I need Spotify =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a cheap USB sound card and redirect sounds using the mixer/control panel. Music via soundcard 1 and other through soundcard 2.

Comment: This might be a solution (haven't tried it because I allready have built in speakers in my AIO I'd like to use).